# Can I change the date range in the Lollipop "cellular data usage" chart?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, date-and-time

In Android 4.x I was able to change the date axis on the "cellular data usage" chart to show (for example) what I used in the past 24 hours. In Lollipop, the date range is locked to a static data range. Is there any way to quickly look at a specific date range as in 4.x? How? Thanks!

Comment: AFAIK, Google removed it for unknown reason. The best alternative you can do is use 3rd-party app, but I haven't researched any.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't either, but after setting a data warning and limit threshold, the option of changing the cycle appeared!
lollipop its a little mess of 'hidden' settings

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wants... on previous version, you could zoom-in the graph using 2-fingers and see (let's say, following OP's example) the usage in past 24 hours. On Lollipop, you're given a static 1-month graph only.

Comment: Why oh why is this option not always visible!! Thanks